# программа компилируется без ошибок, запускается эмулятор, но самого приложения нет Android studio

Tags: android-studio

Несколько дней назад все было нормально (и компилилось, и запускалось), вчера решил продолжить, ничего не менял, решил запустить, в итоге на эмуляторе (встроенный в as) нет приложения, но компиляция прошла успешно. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: что значит нет?? вы хотите сказать что оно не установлено на эмуляторе, хотя вы его можете там протестировать? или что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Как я сказал, несколько дней назад все было хорошо, а вчера приложения уже не было на эмуляторе

Comment: оно удалилось? что значит не было, если я правильно понимаю несколько дней назад вы могли протестировать ваше приложение на эмуляторе, а теперь вы этого не можете сделать?

Comment: Да, после компиляции запустился эмулятор, а приложения на нем нет

Comment: то есть вы не можете протестировать свое приложение я так понимаю? вы не пробовали создать новое устройство например?

Comment: Да, аналогичная ситуация, компиляция успешна, запуск эмулятора успешен, приложения нет

Comment: а попробуйте запустить приложение на эмуляторе, после того как вы опять обнаружите что ничего нету, сверните эмулятор и дальше на вкладке run есть стрелка закрученная возле серого квадратика, над кнопкой остановки, нажмите на эту зеленую стрелку и откройте опять эмулятор, должно помочь вроде.

Comment: Добавьте в ответ, вечером проверю

Comment: Это мне не помогло. Однако, я создал новый эмулятор и попытался запустить там, в итоге у меня 2 эмулятора с одинаковыми настройками, но на одном запускается, а на другом нет...

Comment: хм... довольно странно если честно)) получается что вроде как два одинаковых устройства работают по-разному ?

Comment: Получается так, что меня удивляет не меньше. Единственное что у них отличается так это название в "_2"

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить приложение на эмуляторе, после того как вы опять обнаружите что ничего нету, сверните эмулятор и дальше на вкладке `run` есть стрелка закрученная возле серого квадратика, над кнопкой остановки, нажмите на эту зеленую стрелку и откройте опять эмулятор в открывшемся `popup`, должно помочь вроде. Вот эта кнопка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если опять не получится, то будем дальше искать решение вашей проблемы. Я верю что у вас все получится. Удачи :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Было тоже самое.
Помогло удаление файла с расширением .lock в папке .android.android\avd\Pixel_API_30.avd
После этого нужно перезапустить эмулятор

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).